# Breaking main method into method calls

Tags: c#, .net

Currently my main method looks like this :

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
Object o = new Object("object 1");
Object o1 = new Object("object 2");
Object o2 = new Object("object 3");

List<Object> objects = new List<Objects>();

objects.add(o);
objects.add(o1);
objects.add(o2);
}
```

---

I would like to clean the code by breaking the main method down into method calls. However this causes accessibility issues, i.e. objects cannot find an Object because of the method separation.

```
class Program
{

static void main(string[] args)
{
   createObjects();
   objectHolder();
   addObjects();
}

public void createObjects()
{
   Object o = new Object("object 1");
   Object o1 = new Object("object 2");
   Object o2 = new Object("object 3");
}

public void ObjectHolder
{
   List<Object> objects = new List<Objects>();
}
public void addObjects()
{
   objects.add(o);
   objects.add(o1);
   objects.add(o2);
}
}
```

Comment: are u aware of method parameters?

Comment: Just use the default collection initializer.  Instantiate your list and add the objects all in one go. Can’t get much cleaner than that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are a lot of different things you could do to improve this code, but in terms of your original question one good first step would be to isolate your business logic into a separate class that you then instantiate:

```
class Program
{

    static void main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectManager objects = new ObjectManager();
        objects.AddObject(objects.CreateObject("object 1"));
        objects.AddObject(objects.CreateObject("object 2"));
        objects.AddObject(objects.CreateObject("object 3"));
    }
}

class ObjectManager
{
    public List<Object> Objects { get; set; }

    public ObjectManager()
    {
        Objects = new List<Object>();
    }

    public Object CreateObject(string name)
    {
        Object o = new Object(name);
        return o;
    }

    public void AddObject(Object o)
    {
        Objects.Add(o);
    }
}
```

In this code, ObjectManager contains all your business logic. You instantiate it, and in its constructor you initialize the List so that you don't get a null reference later. Then the methods on that ObjectManager can be used to add each of the objects you want in your list.